# How many tab that be created in facebook page using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have created one facebook page.I am developing an facebook application with asp.net 2.0 using C#.I wanted to add one asp page(suppose fb.asp) content to my facebook page. I have one iframe application in facebook,in its convas url given that fb page url.By using graph api I am able to add my application to my page(means content on of convas url to my facebook page).It creates one tab on page.Suppose I wanted to add diffrent tab on my one facebook page then what is concept behind it.Shall I create diffrent application for diffrent tab or one application is enough for creating diffrent tab.How many tab can I get on my facebook page.

```
suppose
Facebook page        :x 
pageid of fbpage     :xx
application name     :y
application id           :yy
asp page that added as convas url for application y :sample.asp
convasurl: http://IpAddress//foldername/foldername/sample.asp
```

Graph url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/tabs?app_id=your application id&method=POST &access_token=page access token.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you're asking is can one Facebook tab application have more than one page and for each page to show up with its own tab marker in the left-hand column.

I don't believe that is the case (I believe you can only have one tab link per application), though if you have internal navigation within your application, you can certainly have several pages under the same "tab".

But I may have misunderstood your question.